# Moving commits branched from master onto a previous commit in master

Tags: git

I'm attempting to move commits from branch "feature" to a new branch, which is forked from an earlier commit than "feature".

Suppose my tree looks like this:

```
master   A - B - C
                  \
feature            D - E
```

I'd like to move my feature commits D and E to a new branch derived from commit A, so that my tree looks like this:

```
desired    D - E
          /
master   A - B - C
                  \
feature             D - E
```

I created branch "desired" from A and attempted to rebase commits in "feature" onto the tip of "desired", but doing so pulled in commits B and C. Why didn't this rebase work, and how can I move these commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's redraw the commit graph in a way that better represents git's data structures.  You have

```
A - B - C <--(master)
         \
          D - E <--(feature)
```

Then you go back to `A` and create the `desired` branch, which gives you

```
A <--(desired)
 \
  B - C <--(master)
       \
        D - E <--(feature)
```

Now I assume you said

```
git rebsae desired feature
```

thinking that the `feature` branch means "commits `D` and `E`".  But a branch isn't a set of commits; it's a pointer to one commit (hence my rearrangement of the graph).  In git commits are "reachable from refs"; there isn't a real concept of a commit being "on a branch" or "not on a branch" beyond that.

So what makes `B` and `C` different from `D` and `E`?  They're all reachable from `feature`; but `B` and `C` are *also* reachable from `master` (which is why you don't think of them as being "on the `feature` branch").

Which brings us to your first question: the rebase command didn't do what you want, because the rebase command as you issued it doesn't know or care about the `master` ref.  The upstream is `desired` (from which `A` is reachable) and the source branch is `feature` (from which `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` are reachable).  So the rebase rewrites `desired..feature` - i.e. everything reachable from `feature` but not reachable from `desired` - and that includes `B` and `C`.

What you want is to make `master` your upstream, so that the command will rewrite `master..feature` (i.e. `D` and `E` only).  That in turn means you want the new base to be something other than the upstream, which calls for the `--onto` option

```
git rebase --onto desired master feature
```

yielding

```
  D' - E' <--(feature)
 /
A <--(desired)
 \
  B - C <--(master)
       \
        D - E
```

(I kept `D` and `E` in the picture to emphasize the reason for calling the new commits `D'` and `E'`.  The original commits *are not* deleted; if they're reachable from refs *other than* `feature`, those refs will still "see" the original commits.  The `feature` branch now reaches two new commits with identity distinct from the original `D` and `E`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
git rebase --onto A C E
```